# Python CSV, adding or changing column data

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a CSV file. Then I have some rules that have to be applied and then create a new CSV based on the rules.

So it could go two ways:

1. Add a new column, with its own header and data
2. Take an existing column and alter the data of that column.

This is what I have so far

```
def applyRules(directory):
    FILES = []
    for f in listdir(OUTPUT_DIR):
        writer = csv.writer(open("%s%s" % (DZINE_DIR, f), "wb"))
        for rule in Substring.objects.filter(source_file=f):

            from_column = rule.from_column
            to_column = rule.to_column

            reader = csv.DictReader(open("%s%s" % (OUTPUT_DIR, f))) 

            headers = reader.fieldnames

            for row in reader:
                if rule.get_rule_type_display() == "substring":
                    string = rule.string.split(",")
                    # alter value
                    row[to_column] = string[0] + row[from_column] + string[1]
                    if rule.from_column == rule.to_column:
                        print rule.from_column
                    else:
                        print rule.from_column
```

The rule as a FROM_COLUMN and a TO_COLUMN, if both are the same, then the column stays the same, but the data must be updated with the rule, in this case just adding a string before and or after the current value.

When the TO_COLUMN is different, then its just a new column with the altered data as above under the new column.

So currently Im just changing the values of the dict, but Im not sure how to get it back to the new CSV etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the output file as a `DictWriter()` object, then you can write out your altered dictionaries quite easily. You do need to determine your extra fieldnames ahead of time:

```
with open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, f), 'rb') as rfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(rfile)
    headers = reader.fieldnames 

    rules = Substring.objects.filter(source_file=f).all()

    # pre-process the rules to determine the headers
    for rule in rules:
        from_column = rule.from_column
        to_column = rule.to_column

        if from_column not in headers:
            # problem; perhaps raise an error?
        if to_column not in headers:
            headers.append(to_column

    with open(os.path.join(DZINE_DIR, f), "wb") as wfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wfile, fieldnames=headers)
        for row in reader:
            for rule in rules:
                from_column = rule.from_column
                to_column = rule.to_column

                if rule.get_rule_type_display() == "substring":
                    string = rule.string.split(",")
                    row[to_column] = string[0] + row[from_column] + string[1]

            writer.writerow(reader)
```